How do I modify a file in a repository from an azure pipeline YAML, after a PR?
Problem:
I want to update and commit a version file after a Pull Request complete in Azure Devops. For example, I have a repository with a "main" branch and a "changes" branch. When I create a pull request to merge "changes" into "main", I want to increment the version in version.h.
I am using Azure Devops pipelines, I have a azure-pipeline.yaml file that is triggered when a pull request is created. The yaml executes and it increments version.h, however, I always fail the step to push the version.h file. I do not know how to add it to the current merge request.
I have all the permissions required as defined here.
Tried:

Triggering on push to main branch, but I don't know how to differentiate between the pipeline version.h push to main or the PR updates pushed to main after the PR completes.
Triggering on pull request, updating the pull request to include change to version.h, but git complains because azure devops has create a merge request and cannot reconcile the change

EDIT:
Apologies, it's a little difficult to describe what I am trying to do. The error I ran into was related to trying to push to a repository that was not synced to the remote repository. The repository used by the azure build agent only checks out the merge commit, so pushing to "main" or "changes" ended up out of date. I resolved this by deleting the /s directory after every job.

You need to provide actual debugging information. Saying "it fails" gives us nothing we can use to help you troubleshoot. Please provide the exact error text.

Generally speaking, I'd recommend making this kind of change before the pipeline. Modifying code after the pipeline passes is an antipattern.

That's a fair point.

It is quite confusing to understand your actual requirements, based on your current description, because when a PR validation build runs, the PR is not yet completed and we cannot push the updated ·version.h· file as a commit onto the temporary intermediate branch refs/pull/$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)/merge, which can only be generated and changed by the Azure DevOps System and which is actually checked out by the PR validation build.
When a PR completes, it generates a PR merge commit on the PR target branch (main). As well recognized as an IndividualCI, it can also trigger a pipeline. You may try the sample YAML pipeline below to be triggered by any commit pushed onto main branch, then to update a version.h file and push the commit onto the main branch. Still not sure why not update the  version.h file in your PR source branch and bring it into PR target branch together with the PR merge commit.
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    exclude:
    - version.h

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  fetchDepth: 0

- script: |
    git config --global user.email "$(Build.RequestedForEmail)"
    git config --global user.name "Azure Pipelines"

    git checkout -b main
    echo test$(Build.BuildId) >> version.h
    git add version.h
    git commit -m "Updated version.h during build $(Build.BuildId)"
    git push origin main




Thank you for your suggestion. I had no idea I could exclude a file from triggering the pipeline. After that, you mentioned pushing version.h to the PR source branch. Do you mean when the pipeline is triggered? Would this not create a conflict with the merge commit?

To update the version.h file in our PR source branch, I mean not to use build validation pipeline to update the version.h file, but to update the version.h file before a PR creation, so the changes will be brought into the PR and then merged to the main branch. I don't recommend running PR triggered pipeline to push commits onto the PR source branch as it will trigger an unexpected loop of PR validation builds upon detecting new commits pushed to the source branch. And we are unable to push commits to the intermediate branch as explained in the answer.

Hi @user2899525, Good day to you. May I know if you would like to use the workaround to push an automatic version file update commit by a pipeline that is triggered by a PR merge commit? Hope it can help resolve your query in this post. Thx for the sharing.

Hi Alvin, I tested your solution and it worked well! Thanks for the help!
